# Angular 2: Condition in *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am looking to build a list of elements within HTML, but on a certain property within that list.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#record of recordsService.records">
        {{record.recordTitle}} -
        <strong>{{record.recordArtist}}</strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Within the #record object, there is an isSingle property which is either true or false.

I would like to skip over false elements in the loop, without having to leave empty DIVs in the DOM

Comment: Simply filter the elements in your component class. There's no need to do it in the view.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a `Pipe` on your array `recordsService.records` to filter only value you want.

`Pipe` is similar to `filter` in angular1:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: I did give this a try, but I wasn't sure how to tell Angular not to render the particular element I don't want. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Take a look at this live-coding video from egghead, this is almost exactly what you want: https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-using-pipes-to-filter-data